# Angular agDatePickerComponent not working on empty or blank ag grid cell

Tags: javascript, angular8, ag-grid-angular

I am using an agrid column in angular version 8. I have a column which is a date field. Which can have blank date as well. Now when I have value inside the cell for example `2023-04-01` and I click on the cell. I get a date picker but when the cell is empty and I click on it instead of getting a date picker. I get an error stating

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'split')
    at push../src/app/common/components/ag-datepicker/ag-datepicker.component.ts.agDatePickerComponent.agInit
```

[My ag grid with date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m75jT.png)

What I tried

TS file code

```
{
            headerName: "Received Date",
            field: "received_date",
            autoHeight: true,
            filterParams: { comparator: agDateComparator },
            cellEditorFramework: agDatePickerComponent,
            cellEditorParams: {
                inlineFlag: false,
            },
            editable: this.checkReceivedDate.bind(this),
            valueGetter: params => {
                return params.data.received_date === "None" || undefined ? "" : (params.data.received_date)
            }
        },
```

What I am expecting is I should get a date picker even if the cell value is blank or empty..

PS: I am new to angular and ag-grid any help would be appreciated..